# Cython comiplation error gcc failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, gcc, cython

I am a new python user.

I try to install the package `scikits.sparse` to help solve a large sparse matrix with Cholesky decomposition.

However I could not install the package.

I am a windows user and using pythonxy 2.7.6

In windows cmd I typed:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=mingw32
```

However I get errors in compiling Cython files and the setup exited with error: `command "gcc" failed with exit status 1`

I have installed Cython correctly and Mingw32/bin are also in my environment variable path.

Hence it would be greatly appreciated if someone can help me out. I really need the package!

Comment: You need to include more info from the traceback if you want useful help.  Also there are many applications out there that handle these problems efficiently.  I recommend [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) if you're interested. :)

Comment: @az6 I would recommend you to download from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/